# React onClick not firing on nested spans constructed recursively

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## Goal

I am rendering text that may have `<span>`s nested to an arbitrary depth, and I want every such span—no matter how deeply nested—to fire `onClick`.

## Problem

While I am able to render these nested spans correctly, none of them fire `onClick`.

## Background

To render these nested spans, I encode the nesting in a `SpanTree` object, from which containment relations can be computed. (All spans can be assumed to be well-nested.) This tree contains `SpanTreeNode`s wrapping the spans themselves, where `SpanTreeNode = SpanNode | TokenNode` is a differentiated union of nonterminal `SpanNode`s and terminal `TokenNode`s.

I use the `SpanTree` to condition recursive calls to a `TaggedTokenSpan` function component, whose children may be a mix of `TaggedTokenSpan` components and `Token` (function) components. (For current purposes, why these are `TaggedTokenSpan`s rather than merely `TokenSpan`s can be ignored: the `Tag` component is just a vanilla react bootstrap dropdown. Clicking the dropdown button within the span does not reveal the dropdown.) The structure of the `SpanTree` guarantees that (modulo the `Tag` components), eventually, a `TaggedTokenSpan` will only have `Token` components as children. The `Token` components should also fire `onClick`.

## Code

The implementation of the `TaggedTokenSpan` and `Token` components can be found below.

```js
interface TaggedTokenSpanProps {
    annotationScheme: MentionAnnotationScheme;
    activeSpanId: UUID | null;
    activeTypeId: UUID | null;
    tree: SpanTree;
    node: SpanNode;
    onSpanClick: (spanId: UUID, activeTypeId: UUID | null, event?: React.MouseEvent) => void;
    onTokenClick: (tokenIndex: number, typeId: UUID | null, e: React.MouseEvent) => void;
}

export function TaggedTokenSpan(props: TaggedTokenSpanProps) {
    const elements = props.tree.containedBy(props.node).map(
        (n, i) => (
            n.kind === "token"
            ? (<Token 
                key={ n.tokenIndex }
                tokenIndex={ n.tokenIndex }
                text={ n.text }
                onClick={
                    (e: React.MouseEvent) => props.onTokenClick(
                        n.tokenIndex, props.activeTypeId, e
                    )
                } 
               />

              )
            : (<TaggedTokenSpan 
                key={ n.subspanId.uuidString }
                annotationScheme={ props.annotationScheme }
                activeSpanId={ props.activeSpanId }
                activeTypeId={ props.activeTypeId }
                tree={ props.tree }
                node={ n }
                onSpanClick={ props.onSpanClick }
                onTokenClick={ props.onTokenClick }
               />)
        )
    );


    const isActive = (
        props.node.kind === "span" &&
        props.node.spanId.uuidString === props.activeSpanId?.uuidString
    );
    const className = isActive 
                      ? "token tagged active" 
                      : "token tagged";

    return (
        <span 
         className={ className } 
         onClick={ 
            (e: React.MouseEvent) => (
                props.onSpanClick(
                    props.node.spanId, props.activeTypeId, e
                )
            ) 
         }
        >
            { elements }
            <Tag annotationScheme={ props.annotationScheme } 
             value={ props.node.type } 
             onSelect={ tid => props.onSpanClick(props.node.spanId, tid) } 
            />
        </span>
    );
}

interface TokenProps extends TokenModel {
    isHead?: boolean;
    onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent) => void;
}

export function Token(props: TokenProps) {
    return (
        <span className="token-text" onClick={ props.onClick }>
            { props.text }
        </span>
    );
}
```

The component rendering `TaggedTokenSpan` does so in the following method.

```js
renderSpanNode(tree: SpanTree, node: SpanNode) {
        const activeSpanId = this._getActiveSpanId();
        const activeTypeId = this.props.activeTypeIds.length > 0
                             ? this.props.activeTypeIds[0]
                             : null

        const handleSpanClick = this.handleSpanClick.bind(this);
        const handleTokenClick = this.handleTokenClick.bind(this);

        return (
            <TaggedTokenSpan
             key={ node.subspanId.uuidString }
             annotationScheme={ this.props.annotationScheme }
             activeSpanId={ activeSpanId }
             activeTypeId={ activeTypeId }
             tree={ tree }
             node={ node }
             onSpanClick={ handleSpanClick }
             onTokenClick={ handleTokenClick }
            />
        );
    }
```

Neither `handleSpanClick` nor `handleTokenClick` call `React.MouseEvent.preventDefault` or `React.MouseEvent.stopPropagation`. For current purposes, they can be assumed to only call `console.log`, which is how I know that my `TaggedTokenSpan`s are not firing `onClick`.

I do know that some children of the component that renders my `TaggedTokenSpan`s are firing their `onClick`s, however. In addition to rendering `TaggedTokenSpan`s, the parent component renders some `Token`s directly (any token not found in a span).

```js
renderTokenNode(spanTree: SpanTree, node: TokenNode) {
        const activeTypeId = this.props.activeTypeIds.length > 0
                             ? this.props.activeTypeIds[0]
                             : null;

        const isMaximum = spanTree.maxima.some(
            n => n.subspanId.uuidString === node.subspanId.uuidString
        );

        if (isMaximum) {
            return (
                <Token 
                 key={ node.token.tokenIndex }
                 onClick={ 
                    (e: React.MouseEvent) => this.handleTokenClick(
                        node.tokenIndex, activeTypeId, e
                    ) 
                 } 
                 { ...node.token } 
                />
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In contrast to either the `TaggedTokenSpan`s or `Token`s that are children of them,  these `Token` components rendered directly by the parent *do* successfully fire their `onClick`s (as assessed by the `console.log` call within `handleTokenClick`).

Comment: Can you not put a single onClick on the parent of all the nested spans and capture the bubbled event there? The event target will tell you which descendant was clicked, no?

Comment: Oddly, that route results in the same issue: the `<span>`s rendered by `TaggedTokenSpan` act like dead zones in the way you'd expect if `stopPropagation` were blocking bubbling, but I'm certainly not inserting `stopPropagation` calls anywhere.

Comment: I discovered the issue. `SpanTree`'s constructor maps the interval graph implied by a set of spans into a tree representing proper span containment. To do this, it needs to split spans and assign them new unique UUIDs, which are used as the keys on the `TaggedTokenSpans`. These UUIDs were erroneously randomly regenerated on each rerender. Regenerating only when necessary fixed the problem, which I assume was some issue with identifying components across renders (though I'm still not super clear on why it ended up looking like a stopPropagation dead zone).